# Model View Controller - Who Does What?

Tags: model-view-controller

I keep finding conflicting information overall, nothing authoritative, and nothing specific enough to explain the exact issue that my brother and I are debating about. So can someone put this question to rest and hopefully with some authoritative-type documentation?

In short:
Which of the 3 components in MVC is responsible for determining the size and location of an object to be displayed on the screen?

Comment: The Controller does this. Check out Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad in iTunes you, video 1... Class Logistics, Overview of iOS, MVC, Objective-C

Comment: Do you mean html elements sizes?

Comment: I'm referring to the size of an image to be displayed or a button to be displayed or any other visible artifact that one would see on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The key of MVC is trying to achieve loose coupling between classes. This is done by applying several patterns (MVC is a compound pattern, meaning it's a composition of several other patterns).

In here you find "Strategy between View & Controller", "Composite on View" and "Observer between Model & View/Controller".

There is a lot of debate of how it all should be handled, but the general term is this:

Something happens on view -> View informs Controller

```
                       -> Controller asks Model to change data
                       -> Controller asks View to update display
                       -> Model informs View state has changed
                       -> View pulls data from model
```

^ That's using pulling in the observer pattern which is considered "more correct", but it really is a guideline not a rule. Keeping this in mind, the View is responsible for the location of view objects (using composite pattern), and the controller is just a plugin so the actions know how to be sent to the model. This allows for easy switching between views & controllers. (Which creates bidirectional associativity but that's another story)

Comment: I was pretty sure it's a no-no to have the model talking to the view at all. I don't think it's supposed to know of the view's existence... But as you said, there appears to be debate which is why I'm asking! I'm not seeing the exact answer to my question in this though.

Comment: Sorry for that, but indeed, some want view / model to not know of eachother's existance, other's do. I've always learned it myself by having them know of eachother, then at university there were really mixed opinions between lecturers :)